# The Year does not appear in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I have a problem with the latex bibliography. the year does not appear in the bibliography, if I don't mention the pages:

```
@article {model to follow,
  title = "The ...",
  journal = "P...",
  volume = "19",
  number = "1--12",

  year = "1953",
  doi = "10...",
  author = "P..."
}
```

[image]

with **pages   = "888--896",**

```
@article {model to follow,
  title = "The ...",
  journal = "P...",
  volume = "19",
  number = "1--12",
  pages   = "888--896",
  year = "1953",
  doi = "10...",
  author = "P..."
}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\biboptions{sort&compress}
 ....
\section*{References}
\bibliography{mybibfile}
```

[image]

The problem is that I have some bibliography without **"pages ="** but I must appear the years...!

Answer (score 2):

The `bst` style `elsarticle-num` prints the year only if a page value exists. 
Here is a modified style which prints the year if pages are missing:
http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/tmp/my-elsarticle-num.bst

Save it in your documents directory and use

```
 \bibliographystyle{my-elsarticle-num}
```